# Trying to make a chart using `directive` not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a chart using `angularjs` - `directive` but i am not getting the result. I am on learning position with `angular` any one can help me to sort my issue?

index page : (default)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="tempApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <base href="/">
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#/current">Current</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/history">History</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/raphael/raphael.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/morris.js/morris.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

on click history html : (partial)

```
Minimum temperature: <input ng-model='tempMin' type='number'/> Celcius

<chart  "historyData | minimum:tempMin"></chart> //i am trying to load chart here.
```

my controller for load chart :

```
tempApp
.directive('chart', function () {
    return {
        template: '<div id="container"></div>',

        link : function (scope, element, atrr) {
            var chart = new Morris.Line({
                        // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
                        element: 'container',
                        // The name of the data record attribute that contains x-values.
                        xkey: 'date',
                        // A list of names of data record attributes that contain y-values.
                        ykeys: ['temp'],
                        // Labels for the ykeys -- will be displayed when you hoverover the // chart.
                        labels: ['Temperature']
                    });

            scope.$watch(function() {
                chart.setData(angular.copy(JSON.parse(attrs.data)));
            });
        }
    }
});
```

error i am getting :

```
ReferenceError: attrs is not defined
```

what is wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change ...

```
link : function (scope, element, atrr) {
```

... to ...

```
link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
```

In the scope.$watch, you used

```
chart.setData(angular.copy(JSON.parse(attrs.data)));
```

`attrs`, but in the link function, you defined it as `atrr`; probably a simple typing error.

**UPDATE from CHAT:**

There is no `data` element on the chart tag; it should be something like:

```
<chart data="{{data from scope}}">
```

Anything beyond this is another question; we are getting into how [Morris.js](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html) works which is beyond the scope of this question and should be opened as another new question.

Comment: Thanks for that, after I made change I am getting error as `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u` - help me?

Comment: In the console, you should be able to see what line the error is on ... I don't see anything that would immediatly cause an issue.

Comment: this is what i see here : 

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/js/controllers.js:59:37)
Object.ng.config.$provide.decorator.$delegate.__proto__.$watch.watc`

Comment: Wait ... your change just came through.

Comment: I ma trying to console like this, I am getting result as `undefined` `console.log(attrs.data);`

Comment: What is in controllers.js on line 59?

Comment: Are you testing this in IE?

Comment: No I am using chrome, here is the line in 59, `scope.$watch(function() {
    chart.setData(angular.copy(JSON.parse(attrs.data)));
   });`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75450/discussion-between-3gwebtrain-and-rfornal).

Answer (score 0):

There must be an data attribute on your directive:

```
<chart  data="historyData | minimum:tempMin"></chart> //i am trying to load chart here.
```

Currently, the error you get could be because data is `undefined`.
 But still it wouldn't parse because it is not JSON

Comment: Updated, still not working getting error as 'Unexpected token h
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:5000/js/controllers.js:55:37)
    at Object.ng.config.$provide.decorator.$delegate.__proto__.$watch.watchExpression (<anonymous>:754:29)`

Comment: "historyData | minimum:tempMin" is not valid JSON as I said. Remove JSON.parse() and parse yourself your data, with an regexp for instance.

Comment: I updated like this : `<chart  data="{{historyData | minimum:tempMin}}"></chart>` - I am getting data but chart borkes